# C++ version of TensorFlow

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cudnn

I need to use the C++ API of TensorFlow. Therefore it seems necessary to build TensorFlow from sources, so I do this according to https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources. I want to have the version with GPU support. I run the ./configure with mostly default options.

However when running

> `bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda
>   //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

the following error occurs:

> Cuda Configuration Error: cuDNN version detected from
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/include/cudnn.h (7.0.3) does not match
>   TF_CUDNN_VERSION (6)

I had previously CuDNN 7 installled, but then installed cudnn 6 for use with tensorflow. What can I do?

Comment: You could uninstall cuDNN 7, but it makes more sense to reconfigure TensorFlow to use cuDNN 7 instead of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try disable CuDNN 7 from your environment varaities, and try to put the file in cudnn6 folder to the relative folder in your CUDA folder.

This works for me, hope it helps.

Comment: Do you mean environment "variables"? It would also be helpful to give a description of how to do that, or how to change the build command to disable cuDNN-7.

Comment: Oh, yes, I meant environment variables.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEroNNzqlF4
You could check if CuDNN7.0 is in your system variables, if so, remove it, if not, just try to delete the CuDNN7.0 folder you downloaded.

Btw, I'm now using tensorflow-GPU C++ library on my C++ project, and it works successfully, I recommend to build the library with Cmake and Visual Studio 2015. If you hope to know more details, just let me know, I'm glad to help.